# how to specify search scope and returning attributes together for ldap DirContext.search(...)

Tags: java, ldap

I have a case that I have to use DirContext search API to return attributes for ldap search. The reason is the attribute I want to get is Operational Attribute, and it wont return if I don't specifically set the attribute name on search command.

Can anyone tell me how to specify the search scope and also returning attribute(s) at the same time?

I don't see there are any APIs allowing me to do that. They either allow me to specify SearchControls, or to specify the attributesToReturn, but not both at the same time.

```
search(Name name, Attributes matchingAttributes)
search(Name name, Attributes matchingAttributes,  String[] attributesToReturn)
search(Name name, String filterExpr, Object[] filterArgs, SearchControls cons)
search(Name name, String filter, SearchControls cons)
search(String name, Attributes matchingAttributes)
search(String name, Attributes matchingAttributes, String[] attributesToReturn)
search(String name, String filterExpr, Object[] filterArgs, SearchControls cons)
search(String name, String filter, SearchControls cons)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't, of course. You need to use one of the other overloads that takes a 'SearchControls' argument.

**EDIT:**

> Can anyone tell me how to specify the search scope and also returning attribute(s) at the same time?

The attributes to return are a property of `SearchControls.`